# Foreign Key Mismatch Error with django csv import-export

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I'm trying to import three datasets with csv import-export package for three models: service, library and price. I am getting this error when I try to upload a dataset for the service model.

```
Line number: 1 - foreign key mismatch - "catalog_price" referencing "catalog_service"
```

If I try to add price, I get this error. The library model loads fine.

```
Line number: 1 - Service matching query does not exist.
```

models.py
There are three models: service, library, and price.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    serviceid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
    desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True)
    cpt = models.IntegerField(default= 10000)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Library(models.Model):
    hid = models.CharField(max_length = 8, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    hopid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular library in database')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 2, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length = 5, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 12, null=True)
    updateDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Price(models.Model):
  priceid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
  com_desc = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
  service = models.ForeignKey("Service", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  price_offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
  comments = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null =True)
  library = models.ForeignKey("Library", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

admin.py
This is the admin file. I create the admin for each of the models here. The service and price model do not upload, but the library model uploads.

```
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
    from import_export import fields, resources

    class ServiceResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            model = Service
            report_skipped = True
            exclude = ('id','serviceid')
            import_id_fields = ('desc_us', 'cpt', 'price',)

    @admin.register(Service)
    class ServiceAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = ServiceResource


    class LibraryResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            model = Library
            report_skipped = True
            exclude = ('id','hopid','updateDate')
            import_id_fields = ('hid', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'phone',)

    @admin.register(Library)
    class LibraryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = LibraryResource


    class PriceResource(resources.ModelResource):
    library = import_export.fields.Field(column_name='library',attribute='library', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Library, 'hid'))
    service = import_export.fields.Field(column_name='service',attribute='service', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Service, 'cpt'))

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        report_skipped = True
        exclude = ('id','priceid')
        import_id_fields = ('com_desc', 'service', 'price_offer', 'comments', 'hospital', )

@admin.register(Price)
class PriceAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PriceResource
```

Comment: I guess error is self-explanatory. You are trying to insert a `Price` for a `Service` that doesn't exist in database. I mean, you are trying to insert a `Price` witth a `service_id` code that is not in database. You should to insert `Service` data before `Price` data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot insert the service data because I get the "foreign key mismatch" error. Can you help me fix that error?

Comment: Service don't have FKs.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding, how do I fix this error? yes, price has the foreign keys, but I get the foreign key mismatch error when I upload the service model.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to delete (or "truncate") all `Service` data before to import it again and some `services` are referred by some `prices` and this action raises the error.

Comment: No, I deleted my full db at once. I don't think this would happen. I don't understand why library works and services doesn't, when they are essentially the same.

Comment: Could you please post a full traceback?